# Can't mount drives automatically after upgrading to Kubuntu 13.04

Tags: upgrade, mount, kubuntu, 13.04, dbus

I guess it's a problem with kio/dbus or something else since dmesg output is fine and I can mount drives manually from command line. Since the upgrade process was not smooth and I had to

```
sudo dpkg -a --configure
```

to complete the upgrade, I wonder if I'm missing some packages.

I also filed another question about not being able to connect to the Internet at every boot but a

```
sudo service networking restart
```

seems to do the trick. I wonder if the two problems mentioned above are connected.

Can you kindly help me?

P.S.: Dolphin isn't showing my internal hard drives (but they get mounted anyway by fstab) in the panel on the left anymore.

Comment: I've just upgraded to Kubuntu 13.04, and I can't see any of the three problems you mention. If you don't get a timely response here, you might want to post at http://forum.kde.org . They are incredibly helpful there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggestions - something to try**

Have you tried with the new user ? Sometimes the KDE settings get screwed - With the new user the things should/could work. If the things are working with the new user then you could try to fix/reset the old user settings.

Are there error messages in the ~/.xsession-errors ? About error messages: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?59067-Where-are-error-messages-from-programs-launched-from-the-K-menu

The 'Sparhawk' suggested the KDE forum - other forums.

- Kubuntu Forums: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/content.php
- Ubuntu Forums: http://ubuntuforums.org/forum.php

Comment: Thank you so much for your tips. Yes, my kde folder is totally screwed up and I'd better backup my .kde folder to let it create a clean one, but my problems seemed to come from dbus: there was no /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket, so i reinstalled dbus and manually restarted the service to let it create the file I needed. Now everything mounts properly and I have no connection errors anymore.